# How to mock httpclient.getasync method

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

i am writing test cases i need to mock get sync method
please provide help . we are using c#

i am using test case

```
HttpResponseMessage httpResponseMessage = new HttpResponseMessage();
var mockClient = new Mock<HttpClient>();
mockClient.Setup(client => client.GetAsync(requestUri)).ReturnsAsync(response1);
```

but i am getting invalid setup exception

Comment: var response1 = new HttpResponseMessage()
                {
                    StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK,
                    Content = new StringContent("[{'id':1,'value':'1'}]")
                };

               
               

                HttpResponseMessage httpResponseMessage = new HttpResponseMessage();

  my complete code:              var mockClient = new Mock<HttpClient>();
                mockClient.Setup(client => client.GetAsync(requestUri)).ReturnsAsync(response1);

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please be a bit more specific when asking a question: *What have you tried so far with a code example? ([I downvoted because there is no code](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/))* / *What do you expect?* / *What error do you get?* **For Help take a look at "[How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)" and afterward [edit] your question.**

Answer (score 4):

I'd use a library such as RichardSzalay.MockHttp (https://github.com/richardszalay/mockhttp) to create a HttpClient object. For example:

```
// Create the mock
var mockHttp = new MockHttpMessageHandler();

// Setup the responses and or expectations
// This will return the specified response when the httpClient.GetAsync("http://localhost/api/user/5") is called on the injected object.
var request = mockHttp.When("http://localhost/api/user/*")
        .Respond("application/json", "{'name' : 'Test McGee'}"); // Respond with JSON

// Inject the handler or client into your application code
var client = mockHttp.ToHttpClient();

// Test code

// perform assertions
Assert.AreEqual(1, mockHttp.GetMatchCount(request));
```

Answer (score 0):

With `new Mock<HttpClient>()` I believe you are using *MOQ* for mocking and if so you can't mock `GetAsync()` likewise since MOQ is *Dynamic Proxy* based mocking system which allows mocking only `abstract` or `virtual` methods.

Your best alternative would be to create a Adapter/wrapper for `HttpClient` and mock that in this case. Something like

```
public interface IHttpClient
{
  HttpResponseMessage GetDataAsync(string uri);
}
```

Then you can mock it saying

```
var mockclient = new Mock<IHttpClient>();
mcokclient.Setup(x => x.GetDataAsync(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(message);
```

Comment: i am using xunit and moq methods ...is there anyway to mock this method...(httpclient.getasync(uri))

Comment: i am using interface like this... public interface IHttpClientHelper
    {
        Task<TResult> GetAsync<TResult>(string requestUri);
        Task<TResult> GetAsync<TResult>(string requestUri, string token);  }